# How Can I Put <hr /> in the Repeater After 3 Replies

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, repeater

I want to put `<hr />` in the repeater after 3 replies/products.

This is my repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptrProduct" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <figure class="span4 slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="<%#"/images/product/"+Eval("ProductImage")%>" alt="" class="pro-img" />
            </a>
            <span class="title" style="margin-left: 50px;"><a href="#"><%#Eval("ProductName") %></a></span>
        </figure>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And this is my .cs code for bind repeater:

```
BL_Product blp = new BL_Product();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RptrProduct.DataSource = blp.ListProduct();
        RptrProduct.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `ItemTemplare` you have access to the Repeater index `Container.ItemIndex`. From this point you can check [Modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) to know when it's time to add your `<hr/>`

Comment: I'd put an hr in every row, but Eval a mod-by-3 of something available either on the dataset or in a page variable so that only every third one was visible (css)

Comment: Or from the event `OnItemCreated` you can have access the the same `e.Item.ItemIndex `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `<% if ((Container.ItemIndex + 1) % 3 == 0) { %> <hr /><% } %>` below the figure tag closing.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptrProduct" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <figure class="span4 slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="<%#"/images/product/"+Eval("ProductImage")%>" alt="" class="pro-img" />
            </a>
            <span class="title" style="margin-left: 50px;"><a href="#"><%#Eval("ProductName") %></a></span>
        </figure>
        <% if ((Container.ItemIndex + 1) % 3 == 0) { %>
        <hr />
        <% } %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: As one-liner `<%# (Container.ItemIndex + 1) %3 == 0 ? "<hr>" : "" %>`